# Extracting image from video at a given time using OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, video, computer-vision

My task is to make a utility that can take a video and time in seconds.

The utility should write out jpeg images from the video with the given input.

E.g. let the video name be `abc.mpeg` and time be supplied to the tool as `20` seconds. The utility should write out image from video @ 20th second.

```
    # Import the necessary packages
    import argparse
    import cv2

    vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('Wildlife.mp4')
    success,image = vidcap.read()
    count = 0;
    while success:
      success,image = vidcap.read()
      cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % count, image)     # save frame as JPEG file
      if cv2.waitKey(10) == 27:                     # exit if Escape is hit
          break
      count += 1
```

The above code gives all frames of the entire video, my concern is how can I pass time and get the frame at the specified time?

Comment: in C++ you would do `vidcap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, 20000);` to set the the capturing to position 20 seconds = 20000 milliseconds. In python it will probably look very similar. You can use `vidcap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)` to ask for the current position if you want to stop after some given time.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

why don't you just do, what @micka proposed ?

```
import cv2

vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('d:/video/keep/Le Sang Des Betes.mp4')
vidcap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC,20000)      # just cue to 20 sec. position
success,image = vidcap.read()
if success:
    cv2.imwrite("frame20sec.jpg", image)     # save frame as JPEG file
    cv2.imshow("20sec",image)
    cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: thanks now i understood. Also we should use vidcap.set(0,20000) in place of CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC

Comment: ^^ ah, sorry, tried on 3.0, where the constants are more cosistent. it's probably cv2.cv.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC with opencv2.4

Answer (score 1):

```
# Import the necessary packages
import cv2

vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('Wildlife.mp4')
success,image = vidcap.read()
print success
#cv2.imwrite("frame.jpg", image) 

count = 0
framerate = vidcap.get(5)
print "framerate:", framerate
framecount = vidcap.get(7)
print "framecount:", framecount
vidcap.set(5,1)
newframerate = vidcap.get(5)
print "newframerate:", newframerate  

while success:
  success,image = vidcap.read()
  #cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % count, image) 

  getvalue = vidcap.get(0)
  print getvalue
  if getvalue == 20000:
    cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % getvalue, image)  

  #if cv2.waitKey(10) == 27:                     
      #break
  count += 1
```

The output is as follows

```
framerate: 29.97002997
framecount: 901.0
newframerate: 29.97002997
```

Why frame rate is not changing.I want to change frame rate to 1 so that whatever time value user gives i should be able to get image frame.

Comment: As @Micka said to change frame rate, i tried to set frame rate but its not changing.

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('bunny.mp4')
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC,1000)      # Go to the 1 sec. position
ret,frame = cap.read()                   # Retrieves the frame at the specified second
cv2.imwrite("image.jpg", frame)          # Saves the frame as an image
cv2.imshow("Frame Name",frame)           # Displays the frame on screen
cv2.waitKey()                            # Waits For Input
```

Here, ***cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC,1000)*** is responsible for skipping directly to the 1st second in the video (1000th millisecond). Feel free to substitute the value of your choice.

I have tested the code on OpenCV 3.1.0.